# Why URLClassLoader does not load class?

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I have downloaded the `aspectJ.jar` file and extracted it into a temp directory (this jar file is used for test purposes only).
I have the following code:

```
public class TestUrlClassLoader {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("C:\\temp\\org\\aspectj\\lang\\JoinPoint.class");
        URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
        Class<?> aClass = loader.loadClass("org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint");
        System.out.println(aClass.toString());
    }
}
```

A file with `JoinPoint` class exists, but I get a `ClassNotFoundException`. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

According to the javadoc of `URLClassLoader`,

```
[...] (URLClassLoader) is used to load classes and resources from a search path of URLs referring to both JAR files and directories. Any URL that ends with a '/' is assumed to refer to a directory. Otherwise, the URL is assumed to refer to a JAR file which will be opened as needed.
```

You should remove the full path to the `JoinPoint.class` and try with the directory you want to add to the classpath, e.g.

```
File file = new File("C:\\temp");
URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
```

Reference to the javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html